# How to stream HD video from the web?

Tags: streaming

I'm interested if there any web server application that allows you to stream HD quality live chat without software application installed on streaming client PC. Flash Media Server allows HD streaming but it must be encoded prior to that which makes impossible to work with as any streaming client will need to install and handle their encoding software.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean about the installation of software. Naturally you will need to encode your video before it can be streamed, and the client needs some piece of software to play it. That can be software that is already present of course, like Flash or Silverlight.

You might want to look at [IIS Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/expand/SmoothStreaming). It should be able to handle HD quality streaming very well (there's a demo on the site).